# jQuery dragging divs selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

I'm using jquery to make a few divs draggable on a website. My code is similar to this:

```
$("#thediv").bind('mousedown',function(){
    $(document).bind('mousemove',function(ms){
      //drag
    })
});
```

The problem is that if the mouse is too fast for the div, the mouse goes outside of the div. This selects random content on the screen (highlights it blue). It does not give a smooth drag effect. Is there a nice way of fixing this? jQuery's ui drag plugin does not have this problem. I don't want to use it though because it is a large file.

Thanks

Comment: The benefits you get from using full-blown jQuery plugins far exceed their size, in most cases.  The jQueryUI plugin download can be customized to only the features you need, making the actual plugin size smaller.

Comment: It's 27kb. It isn't a ton, but the page I need it on is slow loading already. I don't think it should take 27kb just to make an element draggable. The code I have almost works.

Comment: It will only have to load once and then it will be cached in the browser from then on.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent selection of elements in page just return false from your functions (onmousedown, onmousemove). Also for this functionality you do not need jquery, simply use this pattern:

```
var mouseMove = function () {
    // move div
    return false;
}
var mouseUp = function () {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;          
}
var mouseDown = function () {
    document.onmousemove = mouseMove;
    document.onmouseup = mouseUp;
    return false;
}
div.onmousedown = mouseDown;
```

Don't forget return false from event function mouseMove to prevent default events;

Answer (score 1):

Also consider CSS:

```
#thediv {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```