# Draggable div: behaves like an image on second drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, drag

I have a draggable div in my page. On the first drag it works perfectly. On the second drag it starts to work but then the div seems to be "captured" as if it were an image - the dragging stops, a "copy" of the div appears and the mouseup event is not registered. Identical to this guys problem if i haven't been clear enough: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=227602

Any idea what might be causing this and how to overcome?

Thanks

**Edit:** Ok I have found the answer, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495521/dragging-inside-div-firefox-issue) question. To save future visitors a click, in your `dragStart` function makes sure you end with `event.preventDefault()`:

```
// bind dragStart handler to appropriate element:
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#handle").bind("mousedown", function(e) { dragStart(e) });
</script>

function dragStart(event) {

 // bind mousemove and mouseup handlers to $(document), 
 // get ininitial positions etc

 ...

 // then do this:

 event.preventDefault();

}
```

and hey presto all is good.

Comment: Can you show some code? It's a jquery drag, pure js, html5..?

Comment: If you found an answer, could you please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

@RichardH: also, consider the following in CSS:

```
#handle {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

This will disable that accidental selection of the element when dragging.